# Expand variables in sed

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I need use sed into bash script, for add lines after any line numer of script with some pair of values (below work)

```
sed -i.bak '14i\some_text=some_text' file
```

But I need on script bash (sh) for expand variables (below not work)

```
sed -i.bak '$number_linei\$var1=$var2' $var3
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use double quotes instead of single quotes.  You'll also need to use `{}` to delimit the `number_line` variable correctly and escape the `\`, too.

```
sed -i.bak "${number_line}i\\$var1=$var2" $var3
```

I'd personally prefer to see *all* of the variables use the `{}`, ending up with something like:

```
sed -i.bak "${number_line}i\\${var1}=${var2}" ${var3}
```

Comment: A lot of tanks.  A bit confuse for me escaping. Work for me

Answer (score 5):

Change single quotes to double quotes:

`man bash`:

```
   Enclosing  characters  in  single quotes preserves the literal value of
   each character within the quotes.

   Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of
   all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,  \,  and,
   when  history  expansion  is enabled, !.  The characters $ and ` retain
   their special meaning within double quotes.
```

Comment: Necessary, but not sufficient to fix the OP's problem.

Comment: A bit confuse for me. 
If put a ask, it's because, i was try several options. "", '', and dont' work for me.
After read first response get a mayor knowledg and I can continue my work.